# How to create email notification alerts using Data Factory instead of Logic Apps

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-data-factory, azure-monitoring, azure-monitor

I have been using the Azure Data Factory for a long time. I have created different data pipelines also using the Data Factory. I have used Logic Apps for sending the Email notifications like Status checks, Error messages whenever the pipeline is failed.

I know that we can also send the Email notifications using directly using Data Factory but I don't know how to send it.
Can anyone help me with how I can send Email notifications like status checks, Error messages directly using the Data Factory?

Comment: Any reference? Microsoft suggests to use Logic App. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-send-email

Comment: Is there any way to send the notification alert without using Logic Apps and only using the ADF.

Comment: Can you share the process what you tried for email alerts and what the error you got?

Comment: I can send email notifications using the logic apps and now I searching for a solution to send an email notification directly using ADF but I don't know how to send it. Can you please help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

You can set up alerts in ADF for success or failures etc but those emails wont be custom made similar to Logic apps.
You can use other custom codings like Azure batch or Azure automation to send email notifications which you can trigger via ADF

Comment: Can you please help how I can send the email notifications using the Azure batch or Azure Automation from ADF.